# CSS transitions - rotateX is just changing the size of my element

Tags: css, rotation, size, 2d, transition

I have a problem with CSS transitions.
I have two buttons on my website ([here](http://www.billyvenner.co.uk/)) which are supposed to be pushed back on the bottom of it when the mouse is holding down on it just like on the Windows 8 start menu.
Instead, what's happening is is that it just changes the size of my element and is just like a 2D transition and any 3D I can notice is the element being pushed back at the top. This does not differ even if I set the amount of degrees to positive or negative.
I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this, thank you. :)

,#metroicons is the container, .metro is the element I am trying to rotate 3d, .metro img is an image inside the div and .metro div is some text inside the element. You can see for yourself [here](http://www.billyvenner.co.uk/).

```
#metroicons {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    perspective: 1000;
}

.metro {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 120px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 0.25s linear;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px #000;
}
.metro:active {
    transform: rotateX(40deg);
}
.metro img {
    width: 30%;
    height: 45%;
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-top: 13%;
}
.metro div {
    font-family: Segoe UI, Frutiger, Frutiger Linotype, Dejavu Sans, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get you started.

```
<div class="tile">
</div>

div.tile {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:20px;
    background:red;
    -webkit-animation: example 0.75s ease 0s infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {
       -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateX(-45deg);
       -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    }
    to {
       -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateX(0deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5x0uunkz/

Comment: Thank you, I managed to fix the rotation so it comes from the center X by changing the origin to 50% 0%.